# Re-indexing without having aliases defined before it

Tags: elasticsearch

Every time someone describes an Elasticsearch re-indexing process it is assumed that the index is accessed via an alias. The actual transition from one index to another is then done by changing said alias. My application however doesn't access an alias but an actual index. On top of that I can't change the index name the application is accessing. Is it possible to make a transition from the old index to a new index using an alias with the old index name, hence the application not having to know anything has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem you will face is that you are not allowed to create an alias that has the same name as an existing index (and vice versa).

So if you can't change what your app is hitting and it is currently hitting the index A directly, you cannot create another index B with alias A.

The only way to do it, is to:

1. copy/re-index index A into the new index B
2. delete index A first
3. and then immediately add alias A onto index B (but during the few seconds between 2 and 3, your app will hit nothing)

It will only be a problem the first time you do it, though. The next time, you'll be able to switch the alias from index B (old) to index C (new)  atomically and your app won't feel a thing.